# Python Pandas DataFrame() conversion to iat[]

Tags: python, pandas

I dont really get how I can change what I have to the updated code.

val1 is just an example name, my real code has a bunch of columns to set column names and then write in a column sets from another file.

```
 dfnew = pd.DataFrame(
    {'val1': val}, index = index)
```

How could I do the same thing with the updated code using .at[] or .iat[]

Comment: can you give an example what you want to do with `.at[]` and `iat[]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `at`/`iat` if you only need to get or set a single value in a DataFrame.

**[DataFrame.at](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)**

> Access a single value for a row/column **label** pair.

**[DataFrame.iat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html)**

> Access a single value for a row/column pair by **integer position**.

**Examples**

---

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 2, 3],
...                    [0, 4, 1],
...                    [10, 20, 30]],
...                   columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
>>> df.iat[1, 2]  # Get value at specified row/column pair
1
>>> df.iat[1, 2] = 10  # Set value at specified row/column pair
>>> df.iat[1, 2]
10
>>> df
    A   B   C
0   0   2   3
1   0   4  10
2  10  20  30
>>> df.at[1, 'B']  # Get value at specified row/column pair
4
>>> df.at[1, 'B'] = 10  # Set value at specified row/column pair
>>> df.at[1, 'B']
10
>>> df
    A   B   C
0   0   2   3
1   0  10  10
2  10  20  30
```